# Codeigniter, Vanilla JS: Sending Ajax post request but not recieving any data in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, request

Good Day Everyone
I have a little problem with sending and recieving post data with ajax. I'm not new to this matter. I just recently started using the codeigniter framework, and now, the pattern I have always used for ajax doesn't work anymore. (Never used a 'foreign' framework before, but my own)
I hope you can help me.

The main problem is, that the php controller doesn't recieve the post data.

**ajax.js** (ajax handling, **AJAX_URL** is 'http://localhost/ajax/process' at the moment of th call, I already checked that):

```
function AjaxRequest(callback, data) {
   this.data     = (data!== undefined) ? data : [];
   this.callback = callback;
   this.request  = new XMLHttpRequest();

   this.addData = function(key, value) {
      this.data[key] = value;
   };

   this.send = function() {
      var callback = this.callback;
      this.request.open('POST', <b>AJAX_URL</b>, true);
      this.request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      this.request.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            callback(this.responseXML);
         }
      };

      var data = this.createPostData();
      this.request.send(data); 
   };

   this.createPostData = function() {
      var data = '';
      for (var key in this.data) {
         data += key + '=' + this.data[key] + '&';
      }
      data = data.slice(0, -1);
      console.log(data);
   };
}
```

**actions.js** (contains action handling from website):

```
function requestLogin() {
   var username = $("input#txtUsername").val();
   var password = $("input#txtPassword").val();

   var request = new AjaxRequest(callbackLogin);
   request.addData('action'  , 'login_user');
   request.addData('username', username);
   request.addData('password', password);
   request.send();
}

function callbackLogin(xml) {
   console.log(xml);
}
```

**Ajax.php** (CI_Controller for ajax request handling):

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();  

      $this->load->library('session');
      $this->load->model('user_model');
   }

   public function process() {
      $data = $this->input->post();
      $action = $data['action'];
      if (method_exists($this, $action)) {
         $this->$action($data);
      }
   }

   public function login_user($data) {
      $passwd_enc = md5($data['password']);
      $xml_resp   = new Xml_response();

      $user = $this->user_model->login_user($data['username'], $passwd_enc);
      $xml_resp->start();
      if (!$user) {
         $xml_resp->error();
         $xml_resp->send_message(Xml_message::ERROR, 'Benutzername oder Kennwort ist inkorrekt.');
      } else {
         $xml_resp->success();
         $xml_resp->send_message(Xml_message::SUCCESS, 'Sie wurden erfolgreich angemeldet.');
         $xml_resp->send_data('user', $user);
      }
      $xml_resp->end();
   }
}
```

Now when I try to send the request, the method **process** is called (checked through logging) but the post array is empty (in each possibility: $_POST or codeigniter's own post array) and I recieve a responseXML which is **null**.

Is there anything I have done wrong in this part or do I have to consider something else when using codeigniter?

Thank you very much in advance and please don't be shocked by my bad english (I come from Switzerland ;)

Best Regards, Tobias Widner

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually returning any data from your `login_user()` function. Can you try adding the line `return $xml_resp;` at the bottom of the function?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that. The call **$xml_resp->end();** does an **echo** with the entire xml content (in general). But the call doesn't even happen, because I don't recieve ANY post data (so the variable $_POST['action'] doesn't contain the action I send from javascript, so the function **login_user** doesn't get called either.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash at the end of your request URL. I don't know if your codeigniter configuration is the same as mine but if I don't put a slash at the end of the URL, my .htaccess redirects to the URL with a slash on. This redirect removes any post data.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Is it possible, that I have to config the Ajax controller in a route?

Comment: OK I tried your code and I can see in the web inspector that the JS is not sending any data. It looks as though there might be an error in the send method. Since you are using jQuery for other things I would recommend just using $.ajax to send the request. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I'm always a little reluctant to use jquery (don't ask me why, I don't know). But it actually works! :) I don't know why, but it would be interesting to know, why it didn't work with vanilla js.